# How to display total value of a numeric column in the last row of the table using UITableview or UICollectionView?

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I want to display the added value of a column in the last row of a table using UITableView or UICollectionView. How to do it?
[This is my collectionView and I have used MultiDirectional Property in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMbek.png)

Thank You in advance.

Comment: can you please post screenshot of your tableview with rows and columns as you written,
so it can help to answer

Comment: I posted it now. Thank you so much for your kind consideration.

Answer (score 0):

For table view.

```
viewDidLoad()
{
    int Column0 = 0;
}
```

For each row's textFields attach tags in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
cell.txt0.tag = 0;
Column0 = Column0 + [cell.txt0.text intValue];
cell.txt1.tag = 1;
```

& on `UITextField` delegate method

```
switch(textField.tag)
{
  case 0:
       column0 = column0 + [textField.text intValue];
}
```

Manage your logic as per this suggestion for minus as well